# how to fix my listview with two or three SetOnClickListener

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am beginner in xamarin android and am looking for a way to make my code work as will ,

my code contain three textview title ,main and history also two button share button and counter per click

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var item = items[position];
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
                view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.list_ticket_view, null);
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.titletxt).Text = item.title;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.maintxt).Text = item.main;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txthistory).Text = item.history;

            var share_butn = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.share_butn);



            var button1 = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
            button1.Text = (item.counter).ToString();
            button1.SetOnClickListener(this);


            return view;
        }



        public void OnClick(View v)
        {
            var button = v as Button;
            int count = int.Parse(button.Text) - 1;
            //new two line under this:
            button.Text = count.ToString();
            if (count < 0)
            {
                count = 0;
                button.Clickable = false;

            }
            button.Text = count.ToString();

        }
```

my counter work as well but I cant find way to ork well with share_butn

update : I wana put below code inside OnClick

```
Intent intentsend = new Intent();
                        intentsend.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);
                        intentsend.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText,item.title+"\n"+item.main+"\n"+item.history);
                        intentsend.SetType("text/plain");
                        context.StartActivity(intentsend);
```

Comment: What are you looking to to with your `share_butn` Button? What action do you expect it to trigger?

Comment: do you mean to  add a clicklistener to share_button ?

Comment: Yeh bro i wanna add clicklistener to share_butn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you alse could add click lisetener to imageview :

```
share_butn.SetOnClickListener(this);
share_butn.Tag = position；
```

then in the `OnClick`,you could tell whether it's share_butnor button by id:

```
public void OnClick(View v)
    {
       if(v.Id == Resource.Id.share_butn){
         int position = （int）v.Tag；
         Intent intentsend = new Intent();
         intentsend.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);
         intentsend.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText,item[position].title+"\n"+item[position].main+"\n"+item[position].history);
         intentsend.SetType("text/plain");
         context.StartActivity(intentsend);          
       }
       if(v.Id == Resource.Id.button1){
         var button = v as Button;
        int count = int.Parse(button.Text) - 1;
        //new two line under this:
        button.Text = count.ToString();
        if (count < 0)
        {
            count = 0;
            button.Clickable = false;

        }
        button.Text = count.ToString();
       }


    }
```

Comment: hi best bro , now I wanna add this code inside : I update my question

Comment: when click sharebutton，startActivity ？i update the answer

Comment: Its not start activity from share_butn its to share text of title and main and history with social media as whats app or twitter

Comment: I try and get error in line:    int position = （int）v.Tag；
and line:    intentsend.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText,item[position].title+"\n"+item[position].main+"\n"+item[position].history); but I try to fix it with edit to : Int32 position =Convert.ToInt32 (v.Tag); and in PutExtra  change to : intentsend.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, items[position].title + "\n" + items[position].main + "\n" + items[position].history); and work fine for me is it right what iam doing or must change it

Comment: So your answer is the right i vote its solved but the right sign not shown

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using native `Xamarin` for `Android` and `Xamarin.Android` has its own way of listening to click events I would suggest you use that:

```
button1.Click+= HandleClick; // Applying the event

private void HandleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Click event code
}
```

**Update:**

Try lambda expressions instead of the above code for your scenario

```
 button1.Click+=(s, e) => {
    // Click event code
   };
```

Comment: I will try it but are you sure in this method can i use item in view outside convertview (item.title)or item.main

Comment: yes you can, you can even get your view in the sender object!

Comment: i get this error : CS0103 The name 'item' does not exist in the current context

Comment: its not effective for ui when I click share_butn like this its open many times and close app

Comment: see my code above I wanna make share_butn outside my view as button1 is inside onclick method

Comment: Can you please explain to me what exactly do you want so I can just finish it in one go?